# How to define a CoffeeScript method in Haml using the ":coffeescript" tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, haml

I am working with Rails and CoffeeScript, and need to define and call a function in a Haml file under the `:coffeescript` tag.

I tried using this code but it generates an "undefined `tabsOnLoadMethod`" error:

```
:coffeescript
  $ ->
    tabsOnLoadMethod ->
      alert 'hello team'
```

I called the method using `tabsOnLoadMethod();`.

error:

```
ReferenceError: tabsOnLoadMethod is not defined
```

Where is this going wrong?

Comment: Please read "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"
and "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)". What is the absolutely smallest Haml code that demonstrates the problem? Currently you gave us nothing to test against. We need to see the definition of `tabsOnLoadMethod`, even if that method does nothing, we need to be able to look at the definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
tabsOnLoadMethod ->
  alert 'hello team'
```

is compiled to

```
tabsOnLoadMethod(function() {
  return alert('hello team');
});
```

I think you are trying to call a function, rather than passing it another function / callback

```
tabsOnLoadMethod = ->
  alert 'hello team'
```

If you want to call this method via html (eg. onclick listener), then you will have to attach it to `this` (using `@`) or `window`

```
@tabsOnLoadMethod = ->
  alert 'hello team'
```

or

```
window.tabsOnLoadMethod = ->
  alert 'hello team'
```